# How to avoid having dates which falls under a particular date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My gridview accepts data for planning trips for a particular team. I need that their trips must not get clash with any other dates.

consider the following scenario.

```
------------------------------------------
| TripName  | FromDate   |     ToDate    |
------------------------------------------
| Delhi     | 01/11/2018 |    05/11/2018 |
| Chennai   | 07/11/2018 |    12/11/2018 |
| Bengaluru | 06/11/2018 |    11/11/2018 |
------------------------------------------
```

the last entry is invalid because it is clashing with the second trip. I need to avoid happening this.

Comment: What do you have so far? How do you add the trips to the GridView?

Comment: i have got calenders in the gridview to accept dates, all i need is to check all the dates must not clash with each other before saving it to the database.

Comment: How do you define which is the good range? The first one in the grid takes priority?

Comment: there are 2 calenders which are named as FromDate and Todate in 'n' number of rows of the gridview. so a date-range starts from FromDate and ends at ToDate. Now,The date-range selected in any row must not clash with any other date -range in any row.

Comment: post your code here, so everyone can check and fix it.

Comment: there are no codes written yet, i was expecting someone be kind enough to give me a solution on this.

Comment: What defines a "clash"?

Comment: no trips can have common dates--that's clash defined.

Comment: anyone can help please?

Comment: What you think about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand well, you'd like to check if there is any intersect between any datetime.

**Updated:**

Define a class with intervals:

```
class DateTimeInterval
{
    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }

    public TimeSpan Length { get { return End - Start; } }
    public DateTimeInterval(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        if (endDate < startDate)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        Start = startDate;
        End = endDate;
    }

    public bool Intersect(DateTimeInterval other)
    {
        if((other.Start <= Start && other.End >= Start) || //left intersect
           (other.End >= End && other.Start <= End) || //right intersect
           (other.Start >= Start && other.End <= End)) //middle intersect
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static public bool Intersect(DateTimeInterval dti1, DateTimeInterval dti2)
    {
        if ((dti1.Start <= dti2.Start && dti1.End >= dti2.Start) || //left intersect
           (dti1.End >= dti2.End && dti1.Start <= dti2.End) || //right intersect
           (dti1.Start >= dti2.Start && dti1.End <= dti2.End)) //middle intersect
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And use here a test example for the class:

```
List<DateTimeInterval> dtiList = new List<DateTimeInterval>();
DateTimeInterval dtInterval = new DateTimeInterval(new DateTime(2018, 09, 10), new DateTime(2018, 09, 20));

dtiList.Add(new DateTimeInterval(new DateTime(2018, 06, 12), new DateTime(2018, 7, 1)));
dtiList.Add(new DateTimeInterval(new DateTime(2018, 09, 05), new DateTime(2018, 09, 15)));
dtiList.Add(new DateTimeInterval(new DateTime(2018, 09, 12), new DateTime(2018, 09, 20)));
dtiList.Add(new DateTimeInterval(new DateTime(2018, 09, 11), new DateTime(2018, 09, 15)));
dtiList.Add(new DateTimeInterval(new DateTime(2018, 09, 5), new DateTime(2018, 09, 9)));

foreach(var dti in dtiList)
{                          
   Console.WriteLine(DateTimeInterval.Intersect(dtInterval, dti));
}
```

If you have **DateInterval0, DateInterval1, DateInterval2, DateInterval3, DateIntervalN** you have to check intersects between

- DateInterval0 and DateInterval1
- DateInterval0 and DateInterval2
- ...
- DateInterval0 and DateIntervalN
- ...
- DateIntervalN-1 and DateIntervalN

And in your program, check intersect like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < dates.Length-2; ++i)
   for(var j = i+1; i < dates.Length-1; ++j)
      DateTimeInterval.Intersect(datesInterval[i], datesInterval[j]);
```